# Dashed Line Removed

Tags: modeling

[image][image][image: Image shows that both my vases are connected with a dashed line]

Both the object (Vases) are somehow connected. I think I messed up with some of the controls. Every time I tried to scale one of them the other will also scale up. How can I remove that dashed line?

Comment: that means it is parented to another object. try to move the objects around to find out which objects are connected by the dashed/dotted line then press `Alt`+`P` on the child object but since we can't tell from your screenshot which one is the child or parent object, just do `Alt`+`P` *> Clear and Keep Transformation* both objects.

Comment: Oh, that solves it. Thanks, man.

Comment: you're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like one of the vases is paranted to another. 
Try to use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to *Clear Parent > Clear and Keep Transformation*

Comment: Unfortunately, it's still not working for me

Comment: @DaveO Can you attach the blend file, please

Comment: How do you do that?

Comment: All is good now. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1):

The dotted/dashed lines mean that one object is parented to another object. try to move the objects around to find out which objects are connected by the dashed/dotted line then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> on the child object but since we can't tell from your screenshot which one is the child or parent object, just do <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> *> Clear and Keep Transformation* on both objects.

Comment: man, to be honest this disgusting, copying an answer to a question is all you can do?

Comment: i did not copy your answer. your answer was of low quality and not specific. besides check my answer track record, i don't copy anyone. and for the record i did not downvote your answer. someone downvoted both of us

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie If an existing answer already covers a solution to the issue but you feel it needs clarification you can suggest edits to improve it instead of posting a similar one. That way you also help new users improve they're answering skills.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos agreed. will do it next time. thank you for your message. and i apologize to Yuri

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie I apologize too for being so aggressive, it was a bad morning. There was no need for words like that. The main goal is to help people find solutions. You have done a great job. I shake your hand.

Comment: @YuriTitko hey man don't sweat it, let's continue helping out in this awesome community together✌️:)